# Angular 2: Can't inject service in providers with useFactory

Tags: http, angular

I implemented http interceptor service, it works but my problem is I can't figure out how to inject my own service in the provide declaration.

I get run-time error: `No provider for MyService` in the console.

HttpService interceptor class:

```
// all the imports...

@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
              defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
              private router: Router,
              private injector: ReflectiveInjector,
              private myService: MyService){
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  // methods...
```

In my app.module.ts, I have an array of providers:

```
[ 
 {  
    provide: 'MyService', 
    useClass: MyService
 },
 {
    provide: 'Http',
    useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend,
                 requestOptions: RequestOptions,
                 router: Router,
                 injector: ReflectiveInjector,
                 myService: MyService) =>
      new HttpService(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, injector, myService),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, Injector, MyService]
}]
```

I've checked several SO questions/answers, but couldn't find a similar example..

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`deps` only says what dependencies the factory requires (so that they can be injected properly). But it does not actually provide the dependency. You still need to add it to the `providers` array

```
providers: [
  MyService,
  {
    provide: 'Http',
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: I've updated my question so you can adjust, I was using  {provide: 'MyService', useClass: MyService}, in my providers array, but putting MyService only (as you suggested) worked!